# C++ Object Instantiation In a class file

Tags: c++, class, memory-management, allocation

I am making a module/library with a vector class, and I want it to do it properly.

```
class Vector3 {
public:
    float x, y, z;
public:
    Vector3();
    Vector3(float a, float b, float c);
    float length();
    void normalize();
    Vector3* dotproduct(Vector3 *rhs);
    Vector3* crossproduct(Vector3 *rhs);
    Vector3* add(Vector3 *rhs);
    Vector3* subtract(Vector3 *rhs);
};
```

My doubt is in how should I return a new `Vector3` after an operation.

Currently, I am dynamically allocating a new `Vector3` inside each operation and then I return it.

When I use the operation I have:

`Vector3 *v = v2->crossproduct(v3);`

Should I change my operations to:

```
Vector3 Vector3::crossproduct(Vector3 *rhs){
    float a = y * rhs->z - z * rhs->y;
    float b = z * rhs->x - x * rhs->z;
    float c = x * rhs->y - y * rhs->x;
    Vector3 res(a, b, c);
    return res ;
}
```

And use:

`Vector3 v = v2->crossproduct(v3);`

Or will I eventually lose the vector?
Since I'm trying to make a library what is the proper way to do it?
Allocate at the stack, or in the heap?

Comment: Yes you should. No you will not. Why do you want to use pointers and dynamic allocation? It serves no purpose here. Just don't.

Comment: Aside: The proper way to name your `add` and `subtract` methods are `Vector3 & operator +=(const Vector3 & rhs)` and `Vector3 & operator -=(const Vector3 & rhs)`, and add non-member `Vector3 operator+(Vector3 lhs, const Vector3 & rhs)` and `Vector3 operator-(Vector3 lhs, const Vector3 & rhs)`

Comment: Additional aside: I would expect `dotproduct` to return a `float` (or similar scalar type)

Comment: Fixed the `dotproduct`. Shouldn't be `Vector3 & Vector3::operator +(const Vector3 & rhs)` since I want to do like `v = v2 + v3`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I implemente these operations like this:

```
Vector3 Vector3::crossproduct(const Vector3& rhs){
    float a = y * rhs.z - z * rhs.y;
    float b = z * rhs.x - x * rhs.z;
    float c = x * rhs.y - y * rhs.x;
    Vector3 res(a, b, c);
    return res ;
}
```

To use this operator you can simply use this syntax:

```
Vector v1, v2;
auto product = v1.crossproduct(v2);
```

The return as value is most likely optimized away by copy elision, so you dont have to worry about that. And since `rhs` is not modified, passing it as const ref& is the fastest way to do it.

Comment: And what is the main difference when using the `&` operator?

Comment: The reference qualifier (&) is almost like a pointer. The only difference is, that you can not reassign references and they must always be initialised.

Comment: And what if I want the result to be allocated? how should I do it when calling the function?

Comment: The constructor `Vector3 res(...)`will allocate your result on the stack, which is what you want to do for small objects. There is no reason to put it on the heap since you have to care about freeing and it will also decrease performance due to higher cache miss rate.

Comment: That's my goal. So, for these small functions we should use the stack, but if I wanted an important `Vector` to be in the heap, as a result from this operation, should I do like this: `Vector *a = new Vector(res.x, res.y, res.y)`?

Comment: As a additional note, you should avoid raw pointers at all costs. Use `std::unique_ptr` and  `std::shared_ptr` if you are dealing with heap memory. If you don't do that you will most likely get memory leaks in your programm.

Comment: Don't put vectors on the heap. There is no point in doing that, you can only loose precious cycles.

Comment: If you really want to put a vector on the heap do it like this: auto vecPtr = std::make_unique<Vector3>(x,y,z)`. But that is a whole other topic

Comment: If you have big `vector3`, then handle memory inside the class... You want readable and exception safe code.

Comment: Just one more question, if I have a class like this: `class Matrix44 {
public:
 float m[16]; }` and I have this constructor: `Matrix44::Matrix44() { m[16] = { }; }`, everytime I declare a `Matrix44 matrix;` will the array be initialized?

Comment: `m[16] = { 0 }` would hold all `0` values.I would recomend using `std::array` over c-style arrays. `std::array` is a zero overhead abstractions and provides additional functionality like `size()` and plays well with the algorithms in the STL.